# How do I append a jQuery object to a document fragment?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, dom

Say I have

```
var a = $('.someclass');
var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
```

How/Can I do

```
df.appendChild(a);
```

I need to do this to speed up my dom rendering on mobile devices.

Can someone please help me in understanding how to use this fix?

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/9c28a320c3fa6dcc06de4919d24da41451843570

The thinking behind this comes from:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3#modifyingtree

Comment: `$(df).append(a);` perhaps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is:

```
var a = $('.someclass');
var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
a.appendTo(df);
```

HTH